# .NET CF - Socket.BeginReceive - Does this ever throw a SocketException?

Tags: .net, sockets, compact-framework

I have been looking at how calling BeginReceive on a .NET CF socket can throw an SocketException as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw(v=vs.90).aspx?

I looked through the Reflector but I cannot see how this is possible? I think the SocketException is only possible while actually doing the work in a threadpool thread.

My guess is any SocketException is channel through EndReceive().

I have a callback method which calls itself (i.e. BeginReceive(.., .., callback), which contains an EndReceive. I want to make sure that I add a Try-catch in the right place.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try/catch it even if you can't find any reason it would ever happen.  It doesn't cost anything to add the protection and if (I know, big if) the CF ever gets updated, or more likely if you reuse the code on anotehr platform, you stay protected.

Comment: @ctacke you are correct. In fact I have used a try-catch around the whole method...just to cover...most possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and it will throw an exception.

Code:

```
[HostProtection(ExternalThreading=true)] 
    public IAsyncResult BeginReceive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    { 
        SocketError errorCode;
        IAsyncResult result = BeginReceive(buffer, offset, size, socketFlags, out errorCode, callback, state);
        if(errorCode != SocketError.Success && errorCode !=SocketError.IOPending){
            throw new SocketException(errorCode); 
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

In a method that gets called from overloads of the Begin in a method called DoBeginReceive this method calls this code. The errorcode is passed using the out keyword so it is exactly what is passed back.

```
errorCode = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.WSARecv(
                m_Handle, 
                ref asyncResult.m_SingleBuffer,
                1,
                out bytesTransferred,
                ref socketFlags, 
                asyncResult.OverlappedHandle,
                IntPtr.Zero);
```

EDIT: For .NET CF:

As Stated by the OP

This is the Begin Receive

```
public IAsyncResult BeginReceive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    this.throwIfDisposed();
    if (buffer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
    }
    if (offset < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
    }
    if (size < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");
    }
    if (buffer.Length < (offset + size))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("", SR.GetString(0x41, new object[0]));
    }
    ReceiveAsyncRequest req = new ReceiveAsyncRequest(this, buffer, offset, size, socketFlags, callback, state);
    this.addReadRequest(req);
    return req;
}
```

The addReadRequest does this:

```
private void addReadRequest(AsyncRequest req)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        if (this.m_readHead == null)
        {
            if (!startWorker(req))
            {
                req.InvokeCallback(false, new OutOfMemoryException(SR.GetString(0x42, new object[0])));
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_readHead = req;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AsyncRequest readHead = this.m_readHead;
            while (readHead.m_next != null)
            {
                readHead = readHead.m_next;
            }
            readHead.m_next = req;
        }
    }
}
```

The startWorker does this:

```
private static bool startWorker(AsyncRequest req)
{
    WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread(req);
    if (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(thread.doWorkI)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The Thread calls the doWork of the ReceiveAsyncRequestcalls the doRequest of the ReceiveAsyncRequestwhich calls the handleRequest which in turn calls doRequest on the ReceiveAsyncRequest.

The doRequest of the ReceiveAsyncRequest method looks like this:

```
protected override object doRequest()
{
    return base.m_socket.ReceiveNoCheck(this.m_readBuffer, this.m_index, this.m_size, this.m_flags);
}
```

In the ReceiveFromNoCheck it throws the exception:

```
internal int ReceiveFromNoCheck(byte[] buffer, int index, int request, SocketFlags flags)
{
    this.throwIfDisposed();
    int rc = 0;
    int num2 = OSSOCK.recv(this.handle, buffer, index, request, (int) flags, ref rc);
    if(num2 < 0)
    {
        throw new SocketException(rc);
    }
    return num2;
}
```

If the AsyncResults runs [sychronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx), it will throw the exception. However, if it is part of the ThreadPool, the exception will just be thrown and [kill the application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx).

Comment: Not sure whether this the same for .NET Compact Framework sockets?

Comment: @msuhash I cannot say for sure but digging deeper in the .NET code, the error comes from a call to the Win32 libraries. This is the Windows Native Socket Error codes and 99.9% sure will be the same across the platforms. Will post updated location code.

Answer (score 0):

@Brad

This is what I see in .NET CF. I agree with your analysis on the full framework.

Following is for the CF.

(1)

```
public IAsyncResult BeginReceive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    this.throwIfDisposed();
    if (buffer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
    }
    if (offset < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
    }
    if (size < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");
    }
    if (buffer.Length < (offset + size))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(null, SR.GetString(0x44, new object[0]));
    }
    ReceiveAsyncRequest req = new ReceiveAsyncRequest(this, buffer, offset, size, socketFlags, callback, state);
    this.addReadRequest(req);
    return req;
}
```

(2)

```
private void addReadRequest(AsyncRequest req)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        if (this.m_readHead == null)
        {
            if (!startWorker(req))
            {
                req.InvokeCallback(false, new OutOfMemoryException(SR.GetString(0x45, new object[0])));
            }
            else
            {
                this.m_readHead = req;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AsyncRequest readHead = this.m_readHead;
            while (readHead.m_next != null)
            {
                readHead = readHead.m_next;
            }
            readHead.m_next = req;
        }
    }
}
```

The "startWorker" just queues the item in a threadpool thread.

(3)

```
private static bool startWorker(AsyncRequest req)
{
    WorkerThread thread = new WorkerThread(req);
    if (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(thread.doWorkI)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

May be my eyes are playing games but I cannot spot a SocketException.

Thanks,

Comment: look at my answer I edited it to include the CF. It does throw the exception you just have to follow the code. It took me awhile to realize that.

Comment: I Agree, but isn't this SocketException happens within a threadpool theead. Therefore the consumer gets this exception at the point where EndReceive is called?

Comment: Added more at the bottom about this.

Comment: @Brad - I think you are correct. (see this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/ncl/thread/cbfcb773-fde1-48e9-8643-de1efe5dae95). Thank you for your help!